# how to store unique values of column as a list if they satisfy a condition in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to save unique values of column as a list, if they satisfy a condition.
I am getting my syntax/logic wrong. How do i get it in right way ?

Input:

```
ID  Proceed?
ABC  Yes
DEF  No
EFG  Yes
HHH  No
JJJ  Yes
NNN  No
```

Expected Output:

```
['ABC','EFG','JJJ']
```

Code:

```
a = list(df1['ID'].unique().where df1['Proceed?'] == 'Yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
a = df1[df1['Proceed?'] == 'Yes']['ID'].unique().tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
df1.loc[df1['Proceed?']=='Yes', 'ID'].unique()
```